# Eliminate the elements of array into two by multiplying the number more than two

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to eliminate an array of integer of size n, into two numbers only by multiplying the numbers more that two together. the condition of these two numbers (M1 and M2) is that the result of subtract M1-M2 is the less value among other possible cases. 
The following example illustrates the problem in more details:

Suppose the size of the array is 4 and the elements are [n1,n2,n3,n4]

the possible eliminations are:

**M1** = n1        and   **M2** = n2xn3xn4

**M1** = n2      and **M2** = n1xn3xn4

**M1** = n3      and **M2** = n1xn2xn4

**M1** = n4      and **M2** = n1xn2xn3

**M1** = n1xn2   and **M2** = n3xn4

**M1** = n1xn3   and **M2** = n2xn4

**M1** = n1xn4   and **M2** = n2xn3

**M1** = n2xn3   and **M2** = n1xn4

**M1** = n2xn4   and **M2** = n1xn3

**M1** = n3xn4   and **M2** = n1xn2

in this example there are ten possible values of **M1** and **M2**, the correct value that I want it in my problem is the smallest value of ABS(**M1** - **M2**) among other nine values. there is a possibility that they will be more than one right answer (similar), but this can be ignored, the out put that I want it is one value for **M1** and one value for **M2**

Note: I would appreciate if it was in C++ :)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. At least, you should have tried something yourself, and ideally show some **code** of what you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? It looks like you are trying to get the stackoverflow community to do your homework.

Comment: Lacks the minimal understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I sugest to use [`std::next_permutation`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) to generate all permutations of the input array, and for each permutation you use [`std::accumulate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/) multiple times to create the different products (i.e. one product where `M1` is just the first element of the permutation and `M2` is the rest, one product where `M1` is the first two elements of the permutation and `M2` is the rest and so on, until you hit the middle).

This is not optimal though because it generates a few duplicate products, i.e. it will handle the permutation `[n1, n2, n3, n4]` with `M1 = n1 * n2` and `M2 = n3 * n4` and later it will handle the permutation `[n2, n1, n4, 3]` with `M1 = n2 * n1` and `M2 = n4 * n3`. The solution is very simple and easy to write, but it fails to take advantage of the fact that multiplication is commutative.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. However, I have went through this during my searching for an answer to this question before I post my question here. But what I actually want is a lower level answer without using a standard function or an a build-in algorithm such as the one you mentioned. in other words, a solution that can be based on loops for example.

Comment: @MohammedFaiz: Sounds like you may want to ask separate questions for how to implement those standard functions yourself thn.